# Overriding the encapsulated CSS of external component

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I was wondering how to override the encapsulated CSS of an external component.

So I am using [material2](https://github.com/angular/material2) in my project and the tabs component has a the attribute overflow set on `tab-body`. Is it possible to override the overflow value?

Comment: Yes. Create a CSS selector with a higher specificity than the one applying the overflow.

Comment: but that won't override that generated element will still have it's styling

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use the special css `/deep/` instruction. [See the documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html)

So, if you have

```
app
  sub-component
    target-component
      <div class="target-class">...</div>
```

You can put in your apps css (or less):

```
/deep/ .target-class {
  width: 20px;
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

Obviously, you can put this css fragment in `sub-component` as well.

Comment: The `/deep/` is deprecated and support is being [removed from major browsers](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6750456638341120). See the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep). So I would recommend to write in your CSS a class with the same name `target-class` and mark the overridden properties with the [!important](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception) attribute.

Comment: @LppEdd, as a rule of thumb, you should use [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to override previous declarations and use the [!important](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception) attribute as last resort (as it may have been used already). In cases when you need to override the `!important`, use a combination of _CSS specificity_ and  `!important`.

Comment: @AlexKlaus It doesn't work even with a (apparently) greater specifity.

Comment: As of Angular 8, `/deep/` [fails to compile](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30815). `::ng-deep` still works. I have tried using !important and CSS Specificity but in many scenarios none of these two solutions work.

Answer (score 17):

[From this article](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-create-an-angular-2-library-and-how-to-consume-it-jspm-vs-webpack/)

Although the style of a component is well isolated, it can still be easily overridden if necessary. For that, we just need to add an attribute to the body of the page:

```
<body override>
    <app></app>
</body>
```

The name of the attribute can be anything. No value is needed and the name override makes it apparent what its being used for. To override component styles, we can then do the following:

```
[override] hello-world h1 {
    color:red;
}
```

Where override is the attribute, hello-world is the target component, and h1 is whatever you are trying to restyle. (get this right or it wont work).

Your component `hello-world` would be

```
selector: 'hello-world',
styles: [`
   h1 {
      color: blue;
   }
`],
template: ` <h1>Hello world</h1> `
```

I think this is the most elegant way.

---

Alternatively if you are building a library of some sort, you can reset the styling altogether by doing something fancy in your css like:

`:host-context(.custom-styles) {
  //.. css here will only apply when there is a css class custom-styles in any parent elem
}`

So then to use your component you'd use

`<hello-world class="custom-styles">`

But this is way less convenient than the first option.

Comment: this is brilliant. I agree that this is a much more elegant solution than messing with !important

Comment: I think it is better to add not 'override' property but 'override' id to the body element because of CSS selector priority.

Comment: By far this is the best solution for non-shadow DOM components.

Answer (score 10):

```
::ng-deep .tag-or-css-class-you-want-to-override {    
   /* Add your custom css property value. */    
}
```

The syntax `::ng-deep` is used to override outside css class or tags without using ViewEncapsulation.None.

Comment: ng-deep is deprecated, and have been so for quite some time. It is better to disable viewEncapsulation and wrap the styling in the component selector.

Answer (score 5):

I see variations of this question a lot and since this is the top question on the subject I want to give the simplest answer. `ng-deep` and similar functionality is deprecated, so it's best to just rely on vanilla CSS.

**Simply create a CSS selector with a higher specificity**.

Most people (including myself) get hung up trying to do that because they don't understand two things:

1. Angular View Encapsulation
2. CSS Specificity

---

**Angular View Encapsulation**

View Encapsulation ensures CSS within a component only affects that component. To affect other components, you need some global CSS. You can do this by using a global style file like `styles.css` or by disabling View Encapsulation on a component.

```js
@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

---

**CSS Specificity**

When two selectors select the same element, the CSS that actually gets applied is based on specificity: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

You can increase specificity by simply adding more elements to your CSS selector. For example `p.className` is more specific than just `.className`. If you're lazy, you can just repeat a class name to increase specificity. `.className.className` is more specific than `.className`.

---

So to override any CSS in an Angular project, go into `styles.css` and repeat the class selector until your CSS has a higher specificity than the original.

```
.className.className.className {
  color: red;
}
```

Didn't work? Add another `.className`.

Comment: Good Anshwer, Just couldn't understand where this global styles.css is gonna be declared.

Comment: @CesarLopes styles.css is generated automatically when creating a new project with the angular CLI. You can add global style files manually by adding their file paths to the styles array in the angular.json file.

Answer (score 1):

Just check the class that is being applied to the tabs by the external component (use Inspector or any other tool). In your style css file, add the same name of the class for the tabs and set the overflow property along with adding !important to it to make sure it overwrites the previous one. Also make sure your css link to the page is added after the external component css link if any.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

::ng-deep .css-class-you-want-to-override{

/*your custom css property value. like below */

background: white !important;

}

Comment: Hi! Thanks for contributing an answer! Can you pleas add some explanation on how your code solves the problem? Check the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to correctly format your code.