# Angular2 override css on runtime

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I'm using Angular Material2 mixins to build different theme in a file called my-theme.scss. When compiling the project for production, `ng build` will generate a style file called `styles.xxxxxxxxxxx.bundle.css`.

If I want to build a different theme for a particular client after deploying to production server, is there a way to override the theme without recompile and redeploy the app? For example, externalize the css for theme, etc.?

Please note that I don't want to override the customized styles for particular component but only the theme built using Angular Material mixins.

Comment: plz check this link its may be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40178041/overriding-the-encapsulated-css-of-external-component

Comment: @SunilBoricha that's not what the OP is looking for imo.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking if you run the build with the 'hash' removed', you will maybe able to 'substitute' one style.css for one client by an other style.css for an other? 
Take a look [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/3885). You can run ng build with options to remove the hash.
I hope I get you right tough.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to add a `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/theme.css">` into your index.html.  This will take priority over the styles.xxxxx.bundle.css.  You will, however, have to supply the file in the final build in every environment.  You could leave it blank for your current prod build to avoid any conflicts.