# Angular : How can I override a global style from within a component

Tags: css, angular, sass

I'm need to change the position of a [ngx-toastr](https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr/) per component.

For example in component A want it to appear at the bottom of the page not the top right.
From the devtools it's as simple as to change the `top` property of the following class

```
.toast-top-right {
    top: 12px;
    right: 12px;
}
```

to `bottom`

```
.toast-top-right {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 12px;
}
```

But I can't change that from component A. Is there any way I can change a style defined in styles.scss from a specific component?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably this might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40178041/overriding-the-encapsulated-css-of-external-component

Comment: No it doesn't work. I'm not really sure if it's possible to be honest

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `positionClass` property when instantiating the 'toastr' pop-up. Try the following

```js
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private toastr: ToastrService) { }

  showSuccess() {
    this.toastr.success('Success', 'Toastr fun!', {
      timeOut: 200000,
      positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right'       // <-- set position here
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: But would be applied to mobile and desktop. I think that would only be possible using media queries and for that I need a custom class.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you're looking into.

Comment: You see, the notifications are usually display at the  top of the page. For desktop aligned to the right and for mobile centered. BUT, the designer got the splendid idea that for a specific page in the mobile version(with a lot of scrolling) the notification should be displayed at the bottom of the page. That is what I need to do. For that specific page, for the mobile version show the notification at the bottom. For the desktop it should remain at the top-right corner.

Answer (score 0):

Use `:host` in your css of inside component

```
:host {
  .toast-top-right {
    bottom: 0!important;
    right: 12px!important;
  }
}
```

Comment: This would only target the host of the current component, I need to target an element that it's at the root of the page (toast-container or  toast-top-right)

Answer (score 0):

So `:ng-deep` is getting deprecated so you can try to use `ViewEncapsulation`. In your component add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to the `@component` decorator, you will need to import it from `@angular/core`:

```
@Component({
  ...,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

When ViewEncapsulation is set to None the styles you write in your component.scss won't be encapsulated in a pseudo selector so you may override global styles from within component, but of course, ViewEncapsulation is lost.

Comment: If it is the same as `::ng-deep` then the changes I made in component A will propagate to the rest of the components in the application. What I need is a way to change a particular (`toast-top-right`), but that that change is only applied for the specific component that makes the change, not for the rest. I'm beginning to think that is not possible

Comment: Yes it is the same. There is no way to override global styles from within a component style file without removing encapsulation. The other solution posted here is correct, use positionClass to pass a class, try to pass a custom class and see if it gets attached to the toastr element, if this happens then you can pass a custom class every time you need, and maybe you can pass two classes like positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right my-custom-position-class' and the last one overrides the first, may work but is a guess. If works, styles should be declared in the styles.scss or any of it's imports.